# What does ?: mean in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I found the following in a TypeScript declaration file for Angular:

```
interface IDirective{
    compile?:
        (templateElement: IAugmentedJQuery,
```

What does the `?:` after compile do?

Comment: It is a property, the ? makes it *optional*.  Chapter 3.7.1 in the language spec.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

See: [Walkthrough: Interfaces | TypeScript :: Describing Simple Types](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2013/01/24/walkthrough-interfaces/#Subsection_64).

Basically, `?` marks the member as being optional in the interface.

(EDIT: As noted in comments, this is not restricted to interfaces.)

Comment: This is right. To answer the second part, the `:` indicates the introduction of the member's type (in this case it appears to be a function whose first parameter is an `IAugmentedJQuery`).

Comment: This is correct but you may want to add that it is not restricted to interfaces.

Answer (score 47):

In this case, the `?:` is not a single operator, but rather two operators:

- `?` (optional),
- `:` (specify type).

In other languages/cases, `?:` would be [the Elvis Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator).