# Angular: Iterating Over Model Object Properties in ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on an Angular application where I have a Model object with properties of different types. I want to iterate over the properties of this object in my component and generate form fields for each property, unfortunately, it's not working, it is printing nothing:

Here's my code:

app.component.html:

```
<app-principal [model]="model" ></app-principal>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Model } from './model/model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'frontend';

  model = new Model();
}
```

principal.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-principal',
  templateUrl: './principal.component.html',
  styleUrls: './principal.component.css'
})
export class PrincipalComponent {
  @Input() model: any;

  getModelProperties(): string[] {
    return Object.keys(this.model);
  }
}
```

principal.component.html:

```
<li *ngFor="let property of getModelProperties()">
<label for="{{ property }}">{{ property }}:</label>
<input type="text" [id]="property" [name]="property" placeholder="Write Something" [(ngModel)]="model[property]">
</li>
```

model.ts:

```
export class Model {
text!: string;
number!: number;
}
```

Comment: You should apply the Input decorator to model `@Input() model`. And you should pass the data via `[model]`: `<app-test [model]="product"></app-test>`

Comment: have you tried angular [keyvalue pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) ?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using optional `?:` in TypeScript models, use interfaces and initialize the properties. Interfaces come up only at compile time. It checks that the data received follows a particular structure. In your case, the interface can be implemented and initialized the following way:

```js
export interface IModel{
  text: string;
  number: number;
}

export class Model {
  text: string = "";
  number: number = 0;
}
```

Once the interface is initialized, check the structural directives in Angular using a dummy object.

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Model } from '../principal-component/principal.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<app-principal [model]="dummy"></app-principal>',
})

export class AppComponent {
  // Try generating using a sample object
  dummy: Model = { text: "something", number: 2321 };
}
```

If there were no issues, you will get an output similar to this:

[image]

For further reference,

[When to use Interface and Model in TypeScript / Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37652801/when-to-use-interface-and-model-in-typescript-angular)

[What does ?: mean in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23557030/what-does-mean-in-typescript)

Answer (score 1):

If you change the class to an interface, like:

```
export interface Model {
  text: string;
  num: number; // and don't name your variable number (reserved word)
}
```

and load the model with some data, as in:

```
  model:Model = {text: 'someText', num: 5};
```

You should see the template. That said, you're mixing between model and arrays you need to sort out exactly what you're passing through.

Answer (score 1):

@mohsenmadi's answer is close.  But typescript will complain about accessing properties of Model with a string.  So I used `keyof Model` to overcome that.

Another observation is that using a function to populate the for loop in your template is generally not a good practice, since that will be evaluated a lot, and generating a new object every time.  So I tweaked the principal class to populate a `properties` object via `ngOnChanges`, and using that for the for loop instead.  You should also generally use a `trackBy` function for performance.

Nonetheless, here's a working version: https://stackblitz.com/edit/9daxye-54kkty?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

app.component.ts

```
import { PrincipalComponent } from './principal/principal.component';
import { Model } from './model/model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [PrincipalComponent],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  protected model: Model = {num: 5, text: 'test'};
}
```

model.ts

```
export interface Model {
  text?: string;
  num?: number;
}
```

principal.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { NgFor } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Model } from '../model/model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-principal',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule, NgFor],
  templateUrl: './principal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./principal.component.scss']
})
export class PrincipalComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() model: Model = {};

  protected properties: (keyof Model)[] = [];

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.properties = Object.keys(this.model) as (keyof Model)[];
  }
}
```

principal.component.html

```html
<li *ngFor="let property of properties">
  <label for="{{ property }}">{{ property }}:</label>
  <input type="text" [id]="property" [name]="property" placeholder="Write Something" [(ngModel)]="model[property]">
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Object.keys not return the "properties" of a class unless has a value. (Rememeber that typescript always transpile to javaScript) So you need define your class like

```
//giving value by defect
export class Model {
  text: string='';
  number: number=0;
}
```

or

```
//using a constructor with values by defect
export class Model {
  text!: string;
  number!: number;
  constructor(text:string='',number:number=0){
         this.text=text;
         this.number=number
  }
}
```

The another way is pass an object with the properties

BTW, in general it's not a good idea use a function to loop, better use a getter of your input

```
model:any
keys:string[]=[];
@Input('model') set _model(value:any)
{
   this.model=value;
   this.keys=Object.keys(value);
}
```

And iterate over keys

```
<li *ngFor="let property of keys">
    ...
</li>
```